# Unable to extract data from Database and convert it into Json data

Tags: php, json

I am trying to extract data from database and convert it into Json data.

I have a table with an id, image , name and price of the a product. I want to convert these data into Json and then extract them to my website.

```
    <?php
//config is the file where i used to connect php to db

include_once('config.php');

// images is my table name
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `images` ";

$res= mysql_query($sql);

$result = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))

//image is stored as longbob, name as varchar and price as int

array_push($result, array('id'=> $row[0],
                          'image' = > $row[1],
                          'name'=> $row[2],
                          'price'=> $row[3] 
))




echo json_encode(array());




?>
```

Comment: what is the issue? put $result inside json_encode like echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a array_push. Just continue array and do like this:

```
<?php
//config is the file where i used to connect php to db

include_once('config.php');

// images is my table name
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `images` ";

$res= mysql_query($sql);
$result=array();
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))!==false)
{
    //image is stored as longbob, name as varchar and price as int
    $result[] = array('id'=> $row[0],
                      'image' = > $row[1],
                      'name'=> $row[2],
                      'price'=> $row[3],
                      'error'=>false,
                      'error_message'=>''
                ));

}

if(count($result)>0)
    echo json_encode($result);
else
    echo json_encode(array(array('error'=>true,'error_message'=>'No Images')));
?>
```

I think you want this in AJAX right? If you will use in ajax, just put `exit;` on last line of your code.

I also add you error object to you can debug your code or just check if data exists or no.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this after executing the query

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    //image is stored as longbob, name as varchar and price as int
    $result[] = array('id'=> $row[0],
                      'image' = > $row[1],
                      'name'=> $row[2],
                      'price'=> $row[3] 
                ));

}
echo json_encode($result);
```

You have to encode `$result`, not the `array()`.